# How to import files into remix (ERC721 contract)?

Tags: remix, erc-721

I get this error -

> Unable to import "undefined": Not Found

And this flashes onto the screen -

> Loading
>   https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/introspection/ERC165.sol
>   ...

Is there an error in the import?

The code is just taken from github for the ERC721.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.0.0/contracts/drafts/Counter.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/introspection/ERC165.sol";

/**
 * @title ERC721 Non-Fungible Token Standard basic implementation
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md
 */
contract ERC721 is ERC165, IERC721 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    // Equals to `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`
    // which can be also obtained as `IERC721Receiver(0).onERC721Received.selector`
    bytes4 private constant _ERC721_RECEIVED = 0x150b7a02;

    // Mapping from token ID to owner
    mapping (uint256 => address) private _tokenOwner;

    // Mapping from token ID to approved address
    mapping (uint256 => address) private _tokenApprovals;

    // Mapping from owner to number of owned token
    mapping (address => Counters.Counter) private _ownedTokensCount;

    // Mapping from owner to operator approvals
    mapping (address => mapping (address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;

    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC721 = 0x80ac58cd;
    /*
     * 0x80ac58cd ===
     *     bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('ownerOf(uint256)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('approve(address,uint256)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('getApproved(uint256)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('setApprovalForAll(address,bool)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('isApprovedForAll(address,address)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) ^
     *     bytes4(keccak256('safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)'))
     */

    constructor () public {
        // register the supported interfaces to conform to ERC721 via ERC165
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address
     * @param owner address to query the balance of
     * @return uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address
     */
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
        require(owner != address(0));
        return _ownedTokensCount[owner].current();
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the owner of the specified token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to query the owner of
     * @return address currently marked as the owner of the given token ID
     */
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {
        address owner = _tokenOwner[tokenId];
        require(owner != address(0));
        return owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Approves another address to transfer the given token ID
     * The zero address indicates there is no approved address.
     * There can only be one approved address per token at a given time.
     * Can only be called by the token owner or an approved operator.
     * @param to address to be approved for the given token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be approved
     */
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(to != owner);
        require(msg.sender == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, msg.sender));

        _tokenApprovals[tokenId] = to;
        emit Approval(owner, to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the approved address for a token ID, or zero if no address set
     * Reverts if the token ID does not exist.
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to query the approval of
     * @return address currently approved for the given token ID
     */
    function getApproved(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {
        require(_exists(tokenId));
        return _tokenApprovals[tokenId];
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets or unsets the approval of a given operator
     * An operator is allowed to transfer all tokens of the sender on their behalf
     * @param to operator address to set the approval
     * @param approved representing the status of the approval to be set
     */
    function setApprovalForAll(address to, bool approved) public {
        require(to != msg.sender);
        _operatorApprovals[msg.sender][to] = approved;
        emit ApprovalForAll(msg.sender, to, approved);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Tells whether an operator is approved by a given owner
     * @param owner owner address which you want to query the approval of
     * @param operator operator address which you want to query the approval of
     * @return bool whether the given operator is approved by the given owner
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) public view returns (bool) {
        return _operatorApprovals[owner][operator];
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers the ownership of a given token ID to another address
     * Usage of this method is discouraged, use `safeTransferFrom` whenever possible
     * Requires the msg.sender to be the owner, approved, or operator
     * @param from current owner of the token
     * @param to address to receive the ownership of the given token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     */
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId));

        _transferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Safely transfers the ownership of a given token ID to another address
     * If the target address is a contract, it must implement `onERC721Received`,
     * which is called upon a safe transfer, and return the magic value
     * `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`; otherwise,
     * the transfer is reverted.
     * Requires the msg.sender to be the owner, approved, or operator
     * @param from current owner of the token
     * @param to address to receive the ownership of the given token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Safely transfers the ownership of a given token ID to another address
     * If the target address is a contract, it must implement `onERC721Received`,
     * which is called upon a safe transfer, and return the magic value
     * `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`; otherwise,
     * the transfer is reverted.
     * Requires the msg.sender to be the owner, approved, or operator
     * @param from current owner of the token
     * @param to address to receive the ownership of the given token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     * @param _data bytes data to send along with a safe transfer check
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory _data) public {
        transferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
        require(_checkOnERC721Received(from, to, tokenId, _data));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns whether the specified token exists
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to query the existence of
     * @return bool whether the token exists
     */
    function _exists(uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (bool) {
        address owner = _tokenOwner[tokenId];
        return owner != address(0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns whether the given spender can transfer a given token ID
     * @param spender address of the spender to query
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     * @return bool whether the msg.sender is approved for the given token ID,
     * is an operator of the owner, or is the owner of the token
     */
    function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (bool) {
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        return (spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to mint a new token
     * Reverts if the given token ID already exists
     * @param to The address that will own the minted token
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be minted
     */
    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        require(to != address(0));
        require(!_exists(tokenId));

        _tokenOwner[tokenId] = to;
        _ownedTokensCount[to].increment();

        emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to burn a specific token
     * Reverts if the token does not exist
     * Deprecated, use _burn(uint256) instead.
     * @param owner owner of the token to burn
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token being burned
     */
    function _burn(address owner, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == owner);

        _clearApproval(tokenId);

        _ownedTokensCount[owner].decrement();
        _tokenOwner[tokenId] = address(0);

        emit Transfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to burn a specific token
     * Reverts if the token does not exist
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token being burned
     */
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal {
        _burn(ownerOf(tokenId), tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to transfer ownership of a given token ID to another address.
     * As opposed to transferFrom, this imposes no restrictions on msg.sender.
     * @param from current owner of the token
     * @param to address to receive the ownership of the given token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     */
    function _transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == from);
        require(to != address(0));

        _clearApproval(tokenId);

        _ownedTokensCount[from].decrement();
        _ownedTokensCount[to].increment();

        _tokenOwner[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal function to invoke `onERC721Received` on a target address
     * The call is not executed if the target address is not a contract
     * @param from address representing the previous owner of the given token ID
     * @param to target address that will receive the tokens
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     * @param _data bytes optional data to send along with the call
     * @return bool whether the call correctly returned the expected magic value
     */
    function _checkOnERC721Received(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory _data)
        internal returns (bool)
    {
        if (!to.isContract()) {
            return true;
        }

        bytes4 retval = IERC721Receiver(to).onERC721Received(msg.sender, from, tokenId, _data);
        return (retval == _ERC721_RECEIVED);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Private function to clear current approval of a given token ID
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to be transferred
     */
    function _clearApproval(uint256 tokenId) private {
        if (_tokenApprovals[tokenId] != address(0)) {
            _tokenApprovals[tokenId] = address(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/drafts/Counters.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/introspection/ERC165.sol";
```

This compiles. I am not sure about the v2.0.0 on counter. I replaced that with master.

Comment: As food for thought, I would consider it better form to download the files and include them in the project locally to remove doubt about the contents of those files at compile time.

Comment: It is not good practise to import directly from github. use the format:
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
This replaces the github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity part with @openzeppelin

Answer (score 2):

**Import from NPM**

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

with version

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.2.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

**Import from a Github**

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Based on [Importing & Loading Source Files in Solidity — Remix - Ethereum IDE 1 documentation](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import.html)